# What is the good way to get output with u prefix in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility

What is the good way to get string output with u prefix in python3?

I'd like to use a library to do this like six.

I'm fixing assert testing with string output under compatible with python2.

```
import six
assert(repr(six.text_type('TEST TEXT')) == "u'TEST TEXT'")
```

Comment: I don't think getting the same string output either python2 or python 3 is a bad idea.

Comment: Deleting u prefix when it is python2, or deleting b prefix when it's python3. That's currently enough to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3, strings are unicode by default, so you won't see the u prefix.

For testing purposes, you should simply compare the values, not the representation.

```
 expected = u'TEST TEXT'
 assert(actual == expected)
```

Comment: I know. But I want to use the same assert test with string output. That's good for lazy work.

Comment: You can simply compare actual value with expected, which would work in both Python 2 and 3, rather than assert that it is unicode.

Comment: As I used 'repr' in the question code, it was used when making list to string like str([u'test', u'test]). Just for checking working properly, output string comparison is one choice for the lazy task. Currently, I removed u prefix beforehand if it was python2..

Answer (score -1):

In Python3, you can use String formatting to set the 'u' prefix. Please see the example below:

```
print('u{}'.format("TEST TEXT"))
Output will be: uTEST TEXT
```

Please note that this will only work in Python 3 and above.

Thanks!

Comment: The OP wants something similar to Python 2's `repr` of Unicode string, i.e. include quotes, not just tack on the `u` prefix. Also, `str.format` works in Python 2.7 just fine.